# JavaScript for hashing password field in Vaadin 7

Tags: javascript, vaadin7, jpasswordfield

I have a problem finding solution in changing value of password field before triggering action listeners on backend of Vaadin.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfdbH.png)
Here is the thing - when I click "submit" it triggers clickListener and sends this request with cleartext password(highlighted line in screenshot) to backend.

I've tried to use valueChangeListener for password field - didn't work - there is still some request to back with cleartext password.

Placing javascript to listener of "submit" or constructor of the class also doesn't work.

My thoughts on that - putting js to parent component, but I do not know if it's a right approach.

Please cast some light on that,
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.